# "Placet is a Crazy Place" translation question

Tags: short-stories, translation

I've just the read the short story "Placet is a Crazy Place" by Fredric Brown, but living outside English-speaking world I only managed to get a translation version, which despite the best effort of the translator renders the wordplay point moot.

**What were the short and full names of the red-haired girl and her brother?**

Comment: What were they in the translation?

Comment: Well, to translate them back into English would be senseless because their names were completely fictional (not really existing in any language, as far as I know), made up just for the wordplay

Comment: The original English version is available for free at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v37n03_1946-05_cape1736_fixed).

Answer (score 4):

From the UK ebook version of [The Second Fredric Brown Megapack](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20880233-the-second-fredric-brown-megapack).

> *They looked at each other and started to laugh, and I remembered. Of
>   course, Reagan and Michaelina had both been in my botany class, as had
>   Michaelina’s twin brother, Ichabod. **Only, of course, no one ever
>   called the redheaded twins Michaelina and Ichabod. It was Mike and
>   Ike, once you knew them.*** <sub><sup>(small joke here, [Mike and Ike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_and_Ike) is a brand of candy).</sup></sub>

At the end of the story, we learn that the Administrator sent his resignation, however it was mis-read

> *I groaned. I didn’t look at her. I said, “Mike, I’m nuts about you. But—just before you came, I sent a two-word radiotype to Earth. It said, ‘I quit.’ So I’ve got to leave Placet on this shuttle of the Ark, and I doubt if I can even get a teaching job, now that I’ve got Earth Center down on me, and—”*

...

> *My hand shook a little as I read it: **REQUEST FOR ADDITIONAL ASSISTANT GRANTED. WHOM DO YOU WANT FOR THE JOB?** 
>  I looked up at Reagan again. I said, “You’re trying to tell me I sent an answer to this?” 
>  He looked as dumbfounded as I felt. 
>  “You told me to,” he said. 
>  "What did I tell you to send?” 
>  **“Ike Witt.”** 
>  He stared at me. “Chief, are you feeling all right?*